# How to have different android apps with the same SHA-1

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

I want to have the same app in different variations, i.e. let's say 50 apps that are only different from the name, the logo, the app-id, and such stuff. But everything else is exactly the same.

Is it possible that they all have the same SHA-1? And how can I achieve this?

---

I'm asking this because if you want to use Google Login in your app you must provide a SHA-1 and Google only allows around 30 SHA-1 keys added to a Firebase project, so that would not work for 50 different SHA-1 keys.

Comment: if you have same app with different variation than its best to have build flavour then having 50 different apps

Comment: You might be right, but in my case, I need 50 different apps.